# Associate existing entity records (competitor) to new record (opportunity) crm d365 On create message

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I have a requirement where I need to associate records from an entity 'competitor' to entity 'opportunity' in many to many relationship, on create of record, it's a plugin, and it shows null reference.

code :

```
        var opportunity = context.GetInputParameter<Entity>(InputParameters.Target);
      
        var postImage = context.HasPostImage(PostImageName) ? context.GetPostImage(PostImageName) : null;
        var competitors = opportunity.GetAttributeValue<string>(postImage,OpportunityDefinition.Columns.Competitors).Substring(9);
        var compet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NTNMultiselect>(competitors);
        EntityReferenceCollection competitorsReferences = new EntityReferenceCollection();
        foreach (var comp in compet.actions)
        {
            Guid.TryParse(comp.guid, out Guid id);
            var competitorRef = new EntityReference(CompetitorDefinition.EntityName, id);
            competitorsReferences.Add(competitorRef);
        }
       
        //// The relationship to use
        var relationship = new Relationship("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        _service.Associate(opportunity.LogicalName, opportunity.Id, relationship, competitorsReferences);
        Console.WriteLine("The entities have been associated.");
    }
```

Registered on create, post-operation, synchronous, any ideas?

Comment: which is coming null? did you try to debug ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a many-to-many (N: N) relationship, instead of trying to associate the records please try to create a record to the table "opportunitycompetitors". That should help you to get both the records associated.